# Como mandar un array como parametro en DQL (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, dql

***Trato de hacer una consulta donde pueda filtrar datos por el rol.***

**BD:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La consulta en mi repositorio es:**

```
public function vendedores()
{
  return $this->getEntityManager()
   ->createQuery('
     SELECT e
     From App:Empleados e
     WHERE e.roles IN (:rol)
 '   )->setParameter('rol', "[ROLE_VENDEDOR]" )->getResult();
}
```

**Pero mi resultado es:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Poner solo "ROLE_VENDEDOR" igual no me genera resultados, por lo que
> intente colarlo como un array, pero no lo tengo claro.

Answer (score 0):

---

> CON ESTO FUNCIONA

---

```
public function vendedores()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT e
        From App:Empleados e
        WHERE e.roles LIKE :rol
    ')->setParameter('rol', "%ROLE_VENDEDOR%")->getResult();
}
```